# Why does nginx return 404 on my Kubernetes Ingress route?

Tags: networking, proxy, routing, nginx, kubernetes

I have two nginx web servers set up. One is set up on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the other on Kubernetes using the stable/nginx-ingress helm chart.

The Elastic Beanstalk webserver forwards traffic from all subroutes of my domain to the Kubernetes nginx webserver. I can verify these are being forwarded correctly by checking the logs from the Kubernetes nginx. I use an Ingress resource to make sure this traffic is being forwarded to the right Kubernetes service.

**Here is the problem**:
One of the two routes, the main `/` route, is forwarded to the correct service and returns a 200. The other route, `/eks-test`, is supposed to route to the same service, but returns a 404. **How is this possible?**

**Specs**:

The nginx on Kubernetes is running nginx `0.25.1`.

Nginx logs:

```
172.16.10.103 - [172.16.10.103] - - [12/Sep/2019:08:05:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" 703 0.004 [default-eks-test-repo-80] [] 172.16.10.100:8080 8 0.004 200 90dfa37364a5c43e57f12c5fb1a2d86f
172.16.40.108 - [172.16.40.108] - - [12/Sep/2019:08:05:12 +0000] "GET /eks-test HTTP/1.0" 404 9 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" 730 0.002 [default-eks-test-repo2-80] [] 172.16.43.125:8080 9 0.004 404 ef1c81bba75dff2bdd2376799aa93c56
```

First nginx config (Elastic Beanstalk):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    server_name my.domain.com;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://internal.my.domain.lan/;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Kubernetes Ingress resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: internal
  name: eks-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: eks-test-repo
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /eks-test
            backend:
              serviceName: eks-test-repo
              servicePort: 80
```

Kubernetes Service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: eks-test-repo
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: eks-test-repo
spec
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: eks-test-repo
  type: ClusterIP
```

Nginx helm chart values (ones that are not default):

```yaml
controller.ingressClass: internal
```

---

even adding the ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / to my annotations, the path based routing is not working but host base routing is working. is there any changes required in ingress yaml file apart from rewrite-target. why the path based routing is not working. there are many videos available in youtube related to ingress path base routing and if follow most of them but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nginx Ingress does not strip the path of your request.

When you request `/eks-test` on Ingress, the request is forwarded to your service including the path, ending in your container as `"GET /eks-test HTTP/1.0"`. Your container then returns `404`, as it does not have the `/eks-test` route.

If you want to strip the path from the request, you can configure some [rewrite rules](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md) (e.g.: setting the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation).

Comment: Thanks! Adding `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` to my annotations (without the `nginx` prefix) did the job!

Comment: Good to know @LarsS. The new `nginx.` annotation prefix was added to version [0.9.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.9.0) of Nginx Ingress. You must be using an older version (or enforcing the old prefix with the flag `--annotations-prefix`). If you are using such an old version, consider updating for better performance/security.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Eduardo. I am on version 0.25.1 and I was indeed using the `--annotations-prefix` flag. Your answer should help most people.